# jquery fadeout event listener

Tags: jquery, events, fadeout

I have an existing self coded accordian that i now need to attach an event listener to an existing fadeout event. Can I bind a new fadout listener to an existing one? And how is this done? [Here is the accordian i a jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/designmode/AdPWv/)

Comment: There are no `fadeOut` event listeners. There are only animation-ready callbacks. So what do you need?

Comment: As @VisioN said, it's really hard to understand **what** you need, and also **why** would you need that.

Comment: @VisioN +1. May be you can do one thing. If you know which element is getting `fadeOut` then you can apply `$(ELEMENT).is(':animated')` and perform operation over it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As others have said there isnt a `fadeout` event - you could create your own event though - you would add it to the callback for `fadeout` :

```
$(currentSlide).fadeOut("normal", function () {
    // your other code
    $(this).trigger('myFadeOutEvent');
});
```

then you would need to listen for the event

```
 $('.class').on('myFadeOutEvent',function() {
    // do something
 });
```

[See the docs for `.trigger()`](http://api.jquery.com/trigger/) for details

Answer (score 2):

FadeOut does not have an even listener. However, it has a callback, a function that fires after the fadeout is finished. The downside with this is that you will have to specify what should happen every time you use fadeout.

This has caused miles of code for me earlier.

```
$('.element').fadeOut(400,function () {
    //Whatever you want to do after the fade
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can bind function to this element which you want to listen add do your fadout call your operation you want to apply as a call back function

Answer (score 0):

Refer to the doc
http://api.jquery.com/fadeOut/

It says about 2 syntaxes `.fadeOut( [duration] [, callback] )` and 
`.fadeOut( [duration] [, easing] [, callback] )`

You can apply any callback function

Comment: This really isnt a very good answer - should probably be a comment - or deleted !

Comment: A little better - but there are already answers here with exactly the same thing ... why not upvote them instead of duplicating them ...

Comment: It is a reference to the original document. The original document is the official reference and trusted one. The link gives more understanding than other answers.