# Take action after other action is finished

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am fading out an element as follows:

```
$(div.Panel).fadeOut(800);
```

I need to show $(div.Info) only after the fadeOut is complete.

How can I perform an action only after another action is finished?

Thank You!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can use the callback

```
$(div.Panel).fadeOut(800,function(){
    $(div.info).show()
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to define a custom event in your fadeout and attach a listener to it. Something like [jquery fadeout event listener](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10598089/jquery-fadeout-event-listener)

Answer (score 1):

It uses a callback function. All functions or methods jQuery can receive an additional parameter with the name of the function that must be executed after the end of the first processing. Example:

myFunction ("function parameters", funcionCallback);

Comment: Not all of them. Only the asynchronous ones. It wouldn't make much sense with `addClass`